# How to add custom image tag to pagedown?

Tags: javascript, regex, image, pagedown

I'm attempting to duplicate the original `img` tag's functionality in custom `img` tag that will be added to the pagedown converter.

e.g I'm copy the original behavior:

`![image_url][1] [1]: http://lolink.com` gives `<img src="http://lolink.com">`

into a custom one:

`?[image_url][1] [1]: http://lolink.com` gives `<img class="lol" src="http://lolink.com">`

Looking at the [docs](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown) the only way to do this is through using the `preblockgamut` hook and then adding another "block level structure." I attempted doing this and got an `Uncaught Error: Recursive call to converter.makeHtml`

here's the code of me messing around with it:

```
    converter.hooks.chain("preBlockGamut", function (text, dosomething) {
        return text.replace(/(\?\[(.*?)\][ ]?(?:\n[ ]*)?\[(.*?)\])()()()()/g, function (whole, inner) {
            return "<img src=" + dosomething(inner) + ">";
        });
    });
```

I'm not very experienced with hooks and everything so what would I do to fix it? Thanks.

**UPDATE**: found out that _DoImages runs after `prespangamut`, will use that instead of `preblockgamut`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out! The solution is very clunky and involves editing the source code because I am very bad at regex and the `_DoImage()` function uses a lot of internal functions only in the source.

**solution:**

All edits will be made to the `markdown.converter` file.

do a `ctrl+f` for the `_DoImage` function, you will find that it is named in two places, one in the `RunSpanGamut` and one defining the function. The solution is simple, copy over the `DoImage` function and related stuff to a new one in order to mimic the original function and edit it to taste.

next to `DoImage` function add:

```
function _DoPotatoImages(text) {
    text = text.replace(/(\?\[(.*?)\][ ]?(?:\n[ ]*)?\[(.*?)\])()()()()/g, writePotatoImageTag);
    text = text.replace(/(\?\[(.*?)\]\s?\([ \t]*()<?(\S+?)>?[ \t]*((['"])(.*?)\6[ \t]*)?\))/g, writePotatoImageTag);
    return text;
}

function writePotatoImageTag(wholeMatch, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7) {
    var whole_match = m1;
    var alt_text = m2;
    var link_id = m3.toLowerCase();
    var url = m4;
    var title = m7;

    if (!title) title = "";

    if (url == "") {
        if (link_id == "") {
            link_id = alt_text.toLowerCase().replace(/ ?\n/g, " ");
        }
        url = "#" + link_id;

        if (g_urls.get(link_id) != undefined) {
            url = g_urls.get(link_id);
            if (g_titles.get(link_id) != undefined) {
                title = g_titles.get(link_id);
            }
        }
        else {
            return whole_match;
        }
    }

    alt_text = escapeCharacters(attributeEncode(alt_text), "*_[]()");
    url = escapeCharacters(url, "*_");
    var result = "<img src=\"" + url + "\" alt=\"" + alt_text + "\"";

    title = attributeEncode(title);
    title = escapeCharacters(title, "*_");
    result += " title=\"" + title + "\"";

    result += " class=\"p\" />";

    return result;
}
```

if you look at the difference between the new `_DoPotatoImages()` function and the original `_DoImages()`, you will notice I edited the regex to have an escaped question mark `\?` instead of the normal exclamation mark `!`

Also notice how the `writePotatoImageTag` calls `g_urls` and `g_titles` which are some of the internal functions that are called.

After that, add your `text = _DoPotatoImages(text);` to `runSpanGamut` function (MAKE SURE YOU ADD IT BEFORE THE `text = _DoAnchors(text);` LINE BECAUSE THAT FUNCTION WILL OVERRIDE IMAGE TAGS) and now you should be able to write `?[image desc](url)` along with `![image desc](url)`

done.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the edit to the main post.

I see what you mean now.

It is a bit weird how it uses empty capture groups to specify tags, but if it works, it works.

It looks like you would need to add on an extra `()` onto the regex string, then specify `m8` as a new extra variable to be passed into the function, and then specify it as `class = m8;` like the other variables at the top of the function.

Then where it says `var result =`, instead of `class =\"p\"` you would just put `class + title=\"" + .......`

Answer (score 0):

The full line (not only the regex) in `Markdown.Converter.js` goes like this:

```
text = text.replace(/(!\[(.*?)\][ ]?(?:\n[ ]*)?\[(.*?)\])()()()()/g, writeImageTag);
```

so check the `function writeImageTag`. There you can see how the regex matching text is replaced with a full `img` tag.

You can change the almost-last line before its return from

```
 result += " />";
```

to

```
 result += ' class="lol" />';
```

Comment: yes but I would like to keep the original image conversion, how would I make a new function that converts markdown into an image tag with a class?

Comment: @bnynn: umm, you gonna need to explain that a bit clearer. With my modification the original code does exactly that.

Comment: Sorry for misinforming you, what I meant was that I would like to duplicate the `img` tag functionality into another function that uses a different markdown tag. e.g: the original function turns something like `![image][1]` into `<img>` I would like to duplicate that in order to turn something like `?[image][1]` into `<img class="taco">`

Comment: @bnynn: then change the first `!` in the regex to `\?`, that's all.

Comment: sigh it doesn't seem like I am being clear enough. I will have to rewrite this post. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @bnynn: ah -- I think I got it. You need to add a *new* `text.replace` below the current one, with the adjusted regex and calling your modified function. Then your md will accept *both* notations.

Comment: yes! thank you, I will make another post however, as this one is riddled with confusion. sorry haha.

Comment: Did you end up making a new post? How did you end up solving this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I have still not found a solution. I made two new posts, one got two votes and then buried and the [other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009576/how-to-create-a-custom-img-tag-extension-for-pagedown) is in pretty much the same condition. It seems this is a tough one for everyone! If I do find a solution I will definitely post it.

Comment: @Jeremy Richards I just figured it out! currently updating this post with the solution